# NoIP DNS for virtual machine under router

Tags: ubuntu, networking, router, virtualbox, dns

I have computer which runs Windows(Host OS). vmware(on Windows) runs ubuntu as Guest OS.
My router gives Windows Host OS ip 192.168.0.2, Ubuntu Guest OS ip 192.168.0.128
Router forwards packets on 80 port to Ubuntu, where web-server lives.
I use noip.com for dynamic dns(My internet provider gives me dynamic address).
My dyndns is babaj312.no-ip.org

When I open babaj312.no-ip.org in web browser on either Host or Guest OS on my computer it is not working.
If I open babaj312.no-ip.org from any other computer it works

Output from `curl http://babaj312.no-ip.org`

on Ubuntu:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to babaj312.no-ip.org:80; Connection refused
```

on Windows:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to babaj312.no-ip.org:80; No error
```

From any other computer I get output as expected

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the IP address that shows up when you ping babaj312.no-ip.org?

Comment: > babaj312.no-ip.org
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    babaj312.no-ip.org
Address:  158.181.196.203

Comment: Are you pinging from inside your home network or from a public location?

Comment: pings go fine both from local and public

Comment: What I meant to ask was; do a traceroute and post the results, please.